# MongoDB and PHP - use the MongDB for user login or not

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp, symfony

I am planing to create a project in PHP which will be connected with MongoDB due to the MongoDB flexiblity. The goal is to store in the MongoDB some documents that can vary during the time and with MongoDB we can add extra data without changing the structure of the DB, which is not the case with MySQL.

My question is: Is it a good idea to use MongoDB as the unique DB, or should I use it together with MySQL. The MySQL for the data as user login info etc, and the MongoDB for documents.

I am planning to use the Symfony2 framework or the CakePHP.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to use MongoDB as the unique DB. It's a lot easier to use one database and MongoDB can handle the user login info just fine. You may want to change some collections over to MySQL in the future though.

MongoDB is pretty new compared to MySQL so it does have some drawbacks. For one, MongoDB is not as reliable as MySQL so your bound to run into a few bugs. It will also be harder to find answers to your questions as MySQL is far more popular.

MongoDB is great, but you must make sure you have the time to get to know it. If your short on time or are making it for a client, MySQL is probably a better option.

Comment: Interesting answer, thank you. I will try to start with MongoDB and see how this gona work.

Answer (score 0):

If a single DB server can handle the job, I'd stick to MySQL. The frameworks you are going to use have this DB in mind.

Comment: Thank you for the answer facha, but using MySQL as the DB will be complicated because the documents I am storing will vary a lot, where the advantage of mongoDB will play a big role.